# Directory dependencies with rake

Tags: ruby, directory, rake

I'm using rake to copy a directory as so:

```
file copied_directory => original_directory do
#copy directory
end
```

This works fine, except when something *inside* of original_directory changes. The problem is that the mod date doesn't change on the enclosing directory, so rake doesn't know to copy the directory again. Is there any way to handle this? Unfortunately my current setup does not allow me to set up individual dependencies for each individual file inside of original_directory.

Answer (score 2):

You could use rsync to keep the 2 directories in sync as shown here: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/149-rails-engines

Comment: This tutorial uses symbolic tasks, so rsync is run each time (there is no dependency tracking). Running rsync in a file task will fail just as @francisco-ryan-tolmasky-i describes.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know the files to depend on them:

```
file copied_directory => FileList[original_directory, original_directory + "/**/*"]
```

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion put me on track for a similar problem. For it to work with rsync, I had to touch the `copied_directory` so that rake would detect it's up to date an avoid running rsync for nothing.